# Adjusting height and width of Plotly::subplot in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am trying to insert a `plotly::subplot` in a `shiny` application in `R`. The `app` works as intended, except that the `subplot` doesn't update the plot size even after using the `height` and `width` arguments in `renderPlotly`.

How can I adjust the height and width of a subplot in `R Shiny`?

The closest [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501127/r-shiny-plotly-width-and-height-dont-update) that I could find similar to this question makes the user select the desired height and width, which is not what I want as I would like to predefine the plot size in the code.

Code

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(shinythemes)
    library(shinyWidgets)
    library(fontawesome)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(plotly)
    
    # Define UI for application that draws a plotlys
    options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)
    ui =   navbarPage("Title", theme = shinytheme("spacelab"),
                      tabPanel("Interactive Plot",
                               icon = icon("chart-area"),
                               # Show plots side by side
                               splitLayout(
                                   plotlyOutput(outputId = "Comparison_Plots"),
                                   width = "1080px",
                                   height = "1280px")))
    
    # Tell the server how to assemble inputs into outputs
    server = function(input, output) {
    
        output$Comparison_Plots = renderPlotly({
    
    Group_1_2020 = data.frame(Code = c("A", "B", "C", "AA", "AAA", "AAAA", "BB", "BBB", "BBBB", "CC", "CCC", "CCCC"),
                     Count_2020 = c(1,2,3,11,111,121,22,222,263,33,333,363))
    
    Group_2_2020 = data.frame(Code = c("D", "E", "F", "DD", "DDD", "DDDD", "EE", "EEE", "EEEE", "FF", "FFF", "FFFF"),
                              Count_2020 = c(4,5,6,14,24,34,45,55,65,76,86,96))
    
    Group_1_2021 = data.frame(Code = c("A", "B", "C", "AA", "AAA", "AAAA", "BB", "BBB", "BBBB", "CC", "CCC", "CCCC"),
                     Count_2021 = c(4, 8, 6,14,116,128,42,242,263,43,433,863 ))
    Group_2_2021 = data.frame(Code = c("D", "E", "F","DD", "DDD", "DDDD", "EE", "EEE", "EEEE", "FF", "FFF", "FFFF"),
                              Count_2021 = c(8, 10, 12,44,64,85,105,125,96,46,136))
    
    # Merge Datasets
    DF_Merged_1 = 
      inner_join(Group_1_2020, Group_1_2021)
    
    DFF_Merged_1 = DF_Merged_1 %>% dplyr::select(Code, Count_2020, Count_2021) %>% 
      gather(key = Type, value = Value, -Code) %>% 
      mutate(Type = ifelse(Type == "Count_2020", "2020", "2021"))
    
    DF_Merged_2 = 
      inner_join(Group_2_2020, Group_2_2021)
    
    DFF_Merged_2 = DF_Merged_2 %>% dplyr::select(Code, Count_2020, Count_2021) %>% 
      gather(key = Type, value = Value, -Code) %>% 
      mutate(Type = ifelse(Type == "Count_2020", "2020", "2021"))
    
    
    # ggplot
    ggplot_1 = DFF_Merged_1 %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Code,Value), y = Value, fill = Type, 
                 text = paste("Count:", Value,
                              "<br>", "Offense Code:", Code,
                              "<br>", "Year:", Type))) +
      geom_col(position = "dodge", show.legend = FALSE) +
      xlab("Offense Code") +
      ylab("Count") +
      ggtitle("Group 1 in Year 2020 and  2021") +
      theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8)) 
    
    ggplot_2 = DFF_Merged_2 %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Code,Value), y = Value, fill = Type, 
                 text = paste("Count:", Value,
                              "<br>", "Offense Code:", Code,
                              "<br>", "Year:", Type))) +
      geom_col(position = "dodge", show.legend = FALSE) +
      xlab("Offense Code") +
      ylab("Count") +
      ggtitle("Group 2 in Year 2020 and  2021") +
      theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8)) 
    
    # Interactive Plots
    fig1 = ggplotly(ggplot_1, tooltip = "text")  
    fig2 = ggplotly(ggplot_2, tooltip = "text")  
    subplot(fig1, fig2)
    
    })
      }
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Snapshot from original data to show the problem

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `height` and `width` arguments are of `plotlyOutput` you are passing it o `splitLayout`.

Try -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(fontawesome)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

ui =   navbarPage("Title", theme = shinytheme("spacelab"),
                  tabPanel("Interactive Plot",
                           icon = icon("chart-area"),
                           # Show plots side by side
                           
                             plotlyOutput(outputId = "Comparison_Plots",
                             width = "1080px",
                             height = "1280px")))

# Tell the server how to assemble inputs into outputs
server = function(input, output) {
  
  output$Comparison_Plots = renderPlotly({
    
    Group_1_2020 = data.frame(Code = c("A", "B", "C", "AA", "AAA", "AAAA", "BB", "BBB", "BBBB", "CC", "CCC", "CCCC"),
                              Count_2020 = c(1,2,3,11,111,121,22,222,263,33,333,363))
    
    Group_2_2020 = data.frame(Code = c("D", "E", "F", "DD", "DDD", "DDDD", "EE", "EEE", "EEEE", "FF", "FFF", "FFFF"),
                              Count_2020 = c(4,5,6,14,24,34,45,55,65,76,86,96))
    
    Group_1_2021 = data.frame(Code = c("A", "B", "C", "AA", "AAA", "AAAA", "BB", "BBB", "BBBB", "CC", "CCC", "CCCC"),
                              Count_2021 = c(4, 8, 6,14,116,128,42,242,263,43,433,863 ))
    Group_2_2021 = data.frame(Code = c("D", "E", "F","DD", "DDD", "DDDD", "EE", "EEE", "EEEE", "FF", "FFF"),
                              Count_2021 = c(8, 10, 12,44,64,85,105,125,96,46,136))
    
    # Merge Datasets
    DF_Merged_1 = 
      inner_join(Group_1_2020, Group_1_2021)
    
    DFF_Merged_1 = DF_Merged_1 %>% dplyr::select(Code, Count_2020, Count_2021) %>% 
      gather(key = Type, value = Value, -Code) %>% 
      mutate(Type = ifelse(Type == "Count_2020", "2020", "2021"))
    
    DF_Merged_2 = 
      inner_join(Group_2_2020, Group_2_2021)
    
    DFF_Merged_2 = DF_Merged_2 %>% dplyr::select(Code, Count_2020, Count_2021) %>% 
      gather(key = Type, value = Value, -Code) %>% 
      mutate(Type = ifelse(Type == "Count_2020", "2020", "2021"))
    
    
    # ggplot
    ggplot_1 = DFF_Merged_1 %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Code,Value), y = Value, fill = Type, 
                 text = paste("Count:", Value,
                              "<br>", "Offense Code:", Code,
                              "<br>", "Year:", Type))) +
      geom_col(position = "dodge", show.legend = FALSE) +
      xlab("Offense Code") +
      ylab("Count") +
      ggtitle("Group 1 in Year 2020 and  2021") +
      theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8)) 
    
    ggplot_2 = DFF_Merged_2 %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Code,Value), y = Value, fill = Type, 
                 text = paste("Count:", Value,
                              "<br>", "Offense Code:", Code,
                              "<br>", "Year:", Type))) +
      geom_col(position = "dodge", show.legend = FALSE) +
      xlab("Offense Code") +
      ylab("Count") +
      ggtitle("Group 2 in Year 2020 and  2021") +
      theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8)) 
    
    # Interactive Plots
    fig1 = ggplotly(ggplot_1, tooltip = "text")  
    fig2 = ggplotly(ggplot_2, tooltip = "text")  
    subplot(fig1, fig2)
    
  })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Cheers Shah g, can you also please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68796762/plotlysublot-not-showing-both-titles) question?